# using different master page for home page sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to use two master pages one for the entire site collection and another just for the home page. I created a class library and inherited the publishing layout page and i am using this in the pagelyout inherits section. For some reason i am getting the error message

```
"Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPageEx' from assembly 'CustomMetroPageLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1238ef599029b39c'. "
```

Any idea why this is happening. I have signed the dll and added the entry in web.config and added the dll in GAC.

Please let me know if i miss anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to resolve it with a different page layout instead of a different master page. If you disagree with me, the solution to your problem can be found here:

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621877/can-i-use-more-than-one-master-page-on-a-sharepoint-site/11630731#11630731)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, If i create a new page layout it also inherits from the same master page isn't it? I would like to have this new page as an empty page without the title,tree view, header information etc...If i hide these things on the master page it will reflect for all other pages. which is not the requirement. Please let me know if i make any sense.

Comment: you do. so then the only option is following the link I posted above or you need to make the master page more basic so you wont have to hide stuff.

Comment: Thanks you Tjassens. I am using the same master page with different pagelayout and css.